# spring-data-elasticsearch 4.1 onwards missing SpEL template expression?

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

I have a project using `spring-data-elasticsearch` 4.3.1. Index names are dynamically supplied by a IndexNameProvider which extracts the names from the ENV, working totally fine.

Document annotated classes are using the spEL annotation like;

```
@Document(indexName = "#{@elasticsearchIndexProvider.getBibliographyIndexName()}")
```

This works fine for spring-data 4.0.0 RELEASE but fails for every following version with the error;
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/spel/ExpressionDependencies`

[The docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.mapping.meta-model.annotations), which are on version 4.3.4 state this is still possible. What am I missing here?

Edit:

Also adding the dependency directly does not help;

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.19</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Ok, neverminds folks... I had to upgrade my `spring-boot-starter-parent` from 2.3 to 2.6 like other dependencies... If anybody has tipps on how to debug dependency issues better I'd appreciate.